# How to remotely debug Go code with VSCode

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, delve

I run a process inside a docker container that needs to be debugged. The process is started in the docker's entry point via
`dlv debug /go/src/path/to/package --headless --listen=:2345 --log` for the purpose of enabling debugging later in VSCode.

The docker container is started via
`docker run --rm -it -p 2345:2345 my_image:tag`. Note delve's port is exposed.

In VSCode I define `launch.json` as follows:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Attach remote",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "attach",
            "mode": "remote",
            "port": 2345,
            "host": "127.0.0.1",
            "apiVersion": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

Upon starting the "attach remote" VSCode debugging configuration I get
[image]

It isn't crystal clear, but that UI leads me to believe I'm now connected to the remote headless debugger and ready to debug. I have one breakpoint defined which I know would be hit by a request I can send the remote process. I send that request, I get a result, and that breakpoint never hit, indicating that I haven't yet achieved remote debugging.

Is something wrong with my VSCode "attach remote" configuration? I can do command-line debugging with `dlv connect :2345` and actually debug the remote process just fine, which indicates the headless server is functional. I would rather debug with source code, in VSCode though.

Answer (score 1):

Try again with the [latest beta of vscode-go](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-go/wiki/Use-the-beta-version-of-the-latest-Go-extension) (April 2020) (for any time after April 2020, the latest official vscode-go release will be enough)

[`Microsoft/vscode-go` issue 2010](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go/issues/2010) includes this confirmation from [**Ramya Rao**](https://github.com/ramya-rao-a):

> The fix from [#3108](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-go/pull/3108) is available in the latest beta version of this extension. Please do try and share feedback
> The latest version of the extension now has the fix to this issue

And:

> I can confirm that I am able to hit breakpoints now using AWS SAM to launch a linux container with delve and go binaries compiled from Windows.
>
> For anyone still having this problem (like I was before I edited this comment), **take care that the "remotePath" element of your launch.json is the absolute path to the source files as compiled on your local system (not the container)**.
> As implied above - **it's the absolute local path that is added to the DWARF compilation unit file table when you compile the binary**.